# Embedded tweets displaying on Chrome but not Safari?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, twitter, safari

My website dynamically embeds about 20 or so tweets. While testing it using Chrome everything works perfectly, just how I would expect. However, when I test using Safari, the tweets simply do not show up. But when I resize the window, the tweets suddenly appear right where they're supposed to, with the correct size, etc. Has anyone else experienced something similar to this?

Comment: Can you include some code?

Comment: `window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) { var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], t = window.twttr || {}; if (d.getElementById(id)) return t; js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.src = "platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs); t._e = []; t.ready = function(f) { t._e.push(f); }; return t; }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));`

Comment: The above code loads the twitter widget.

Comment: `twttr.widgets.createTweet(tags.taglist[i],
                    tweetbox,{dnt:true, conversation:'none', cards:'hidden'});`

Comment: The above code is inside a for loop which iterates through a list of tweet id's. The variable 'tweetbox' is just a div I've created to hold each tweet object.

Comment: do you find the solution for this ?